# click event listener is only working once without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript

I'm building a todo app and my delete todo actions only triggering once without refresh the page. My expected behavior is on every time the button is clicked,it should delete the corresponding item

```
const setTodos = (todos) => {
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
  console.log("todos saved", todos.length + 1);
};

const getTodos = () => {
  const todos = localStorage.getItem("todos");
  return JSON.parse(todos);
};

const todos = getTodos() === null ? [] : getTodos();

// Render todos
const renderTodos = (todos) => {
  const todoWrapper = document.querySelector("#todo-list-wrapper");
  todoWrapper.innerHTML = "";
  const todoListWrapper = document.createElement("ul");
  todoWrapper.appendChild(todoListWrapper);
  todos.forEach((todo) => {
    const todoItem = document.createElement("li");
    todoItem.textContent = todo.title;
    todoListWrapper.appendChild(todoItem);

    const checkBox = document.createElement("input");
    checkBox.name = "todoMarkDone";
    checkBox.type = "checkbox";
    checkBox.checked = todo.completed;
    checkBox.id = todo.id;
    todoItem.prepend(checkBox);

    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.name = todo.id;
    button.className = "delete-button";
    button.textContent = "delete";
    todoItem.appendChild(button);
  });
};
renderTodos(todos);


// Delete Todos
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-button");
buttons.forEach(function (button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const filteredTodos = todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== e.target.name);
    setTodos(filteredTodos);
    renderTodos(filteredTodos);
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake

Comment: add the event listener inside `renderTodos` - since you call that function to re-render the todos, the event listeners won't be added the second time you call `renderTodos` - or, rather than re-rendering all the todos every time you remove one, just delete the clicked todo from the DOM `e.target.parentElement.remove()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens because you recreate a button within your render code. There are two ways to resolve it:

1. Render your button separately and do not recreate it on every click;
2. Add event listener to a newly created button on every render event.

It is better to use the first approach.

Comment: just remove the deleted `todo` is the BEST method :p